# Differentiation of Function Defined as Integral of Multiple Variables

Tags: calculus, derivatives, improper-integrals, chain-rule

I am stuck on a question regarding finding the derivative $f'(0)$ of a function $f(x)$ defined as $f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{e^{2x}} e^{\frac{-1}{2}(y-sin(x))^2}\, dy $ for $x \epsilon {\Bbb R}$.

I am vaguely aware that Leibniz' Integral Rule is the starting point for this question, but I don't know how to deal with the $-\infty$ in the lower bound of the integral. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

How do I compute this integral? Many thanks for any help given.

Comment: You could split the integral ($\int_{-\infty}^0 + \int_0^{e^{2x}}$). Then you can just pull in the differentiation into the first integral and use Leibnitz on the second.

Comment: @amsmath I will try this out, thank you

Answer (score -1):

We have that $$f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{e^{2x}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(y-\sin x\right)^2}\mathrm d y.$$ Thus, $$f'(x) = \left(e^{2x}\right)'\left[e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{2x}-\sin x\right)^2}\right]+\int_{-\infty}^{e^{2x}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(y-\sin x\right)^2}[-\left(y-\sin x\right)](-\cos x)\mathrm d y=2e^{2x}\left[e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{2x}-\sin x\right)^2}\right]+\int_{-\infty}^{e^{2x}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(y-\sin x\right)^2}\left(y-\sin x\right)(\cos x)\mathrm d y.$$

Now set $x=0$ to obtain $f'(0).$

Comment: So I actually did derive something similar, but aren't there missing terms from this answer?

Comment: @arnavlohe15 Oops, right. There were missing terms.

Comment: how did you compute this integral? Can you show me the steps/explain the reasoning?

Comment: @amsmath Perhaps you saw this before I edited. Is it still wrong?

Comment: @arnavlohe15 I've made further editions. The first term comes from the chain rule applied to the *integral.* The second terms come from differentiating the *integrand.*

Comment: You can solve this integral by change of variables.

Comment: @amsmath Yes, but we leave that for OP.

Comment: @amsmath Actually OP doesn't need to solve the integral as it stands for general $x.$ Since they want $f'(0)$ they may substitute $0$ for $x$ everywhere first. I suspect this will *greatly* simplify the computations.

Comment: @Allawonder If you set $x=0$, you still have to solve the integral. ;-)

Comment: @amsmath I didn't say otherwise. I said they did not need to solve it *as it stands.* The point is that the computations are simpler when you first set $x=0.$ After all, there's no point plodding ahead in a thicket of thorns when there's a better path.

Comment: @Allawonder There is not much of a difference between solving this integral with or without $x$. You can pull out the cosine anyways.

Comment: @Allawonder is it rigorous to substitute x=0 everywhere first?

Comment: @arnavlohe15 Yes. You don't need it I be variable anymore. Your integration variable is $y,$ not $x $

Comment: @amsmath In my opinion there is. It's not just the cosine. There are sines and exponents that don't contribute anything significant (with respect to integration) eventually and only clutter up the space, so why keep them? In particular, I consider the $$\int_{-\infty}^{e^2}ye^{-y^2/2}\mathrm d y$$ to be much simpler (on many counts -- space and time of writing, aesthetics, clarity, etc.) compared with the one involving the variable $x$ above when we no longer need it.

Comment: @Allawonder Well, I don't. ;-)

Comment: @amsmath *Your* cup of tea.

Comment: Will the downvoter please explain what's wrong with this answer so we see how to better it?